# Apache Camel onException does not get fired

Tags: apache-camel

I have this simple route:

```
onException(Exception.class)
  .to("log:com.mycompany.test?level=INFO");

from("sftp://myuser@localhost:/files/?password=mypassword&knownHostsFile=/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts&noop=true")
  .to("log:com.mycompany.test?level=INFO");
```

If I stop the sftp server, from("sftp:...") throws an org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot connect to sftp://myuser@localhost
I would expect that the onException log prints something,  but it does not. Why??

If I enable the sftp server, the route works and the log after from("sftp:...") prints the file content (so, i guess that slf4j is well configured).

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Apache-Camel-onException-does-not-get-fired-td4899276.html